# Question about implementing WebSocket with React and Spring Boot

Tags: reactjs, websocket

When I send a message from the frontend to the "/room-list" endpoint, I can see it being received and processed on the backend. However, the stompClient.subscribe() function in React does not seem to receive any messages back from the backend.

Can anyone help me understand why stompClient.subscribe() is not receiving any messages?
Thank you for your assistance!

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import Stomp from 'stompjs';

function App() {
  const [stmp, setStmp] = useState(null);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/ws-endpoint');
    const stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    socket.onopen = () => {
      setStmp(stompClient);
      console.log('WebSocket connected');
      stompClient.subscribe('/topic/room-list', (m) => {
        console.log('Received message:', m);
      });
    };

    socket.onmessage = (event) => {
      console.log(event.data);

    }

    socket.onclose = () => {
      console.log('WebSocket disconnected');
    };

    socket.onerror = (error) => {
      console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
    };

    return () => {
      socket.close();
    };
  }, [messages]); 

  const sendData = ()=>{
    stmp.send("/room-list", {}, "test!!");
    setMessages("test!");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Messages:</h1>
      <input type="button" onClick={sendData} value="取得" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
package com.example.websocket;

import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class WebSocketController {

    @MessageMapping("/room-list")
    @SendTo("/topic/room-list")
    public String handleBroadcastMessage(@Payload String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
        return "Processed message: " + message;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dp0c.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOjSc.png)

I have checked the backend code, and it seems to be sending messages to the correct endpoint ("/topic/room-list"). However, the React component subscribed to this endpoint does not seem to receive the messages.

If anyone has experience with React and Spring Boot WebSocket integration, or if you have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue, I would greatly appreciate your input.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.